# Place gif behind button Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have added GIF to a button. On tapping the button it will play that gif. I am using the Stack widget to overlap them onto each other. However, I want the gif behind and the button on top of it. Currently it looks like this

[image]

How can I shift the gif behind the button and at the same time make it visible.

My code:

```
  Stack(



                children: [

                  FloatingActionButton(
                    child: Icon(Icons.share),
                    heroTag: null,
                    backgroundColor: primaryColor,

                    onPressed: () {

                      setState(() {
                        isOpen = true;
                      });

                      shareUserProfile();
                    },
                  ),
                  isOpen
                      ?       Positioned.fill(
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/CELEB.gif',

                     fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    ),
                  )

                      : Container(),
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: Just to be clear. You want the following:
1) The button is visible. The gif is not.
2) After tapping the button, the gif becomes visible above the button?
3) Shall be the button tappable after it has been tapped once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place the GIF before in the children list:

```
Stack(
      children: [

              isOpen?       Positioned.fill(
                child: Image.asset('assets/images/CELEB.gif',

                 fit: BoxFit.contain,
                ),
              )

                  : Container(),
              FloatingActionButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.share),
                heroTag: null,
                backgroundColor: primaryColor,

                onPressed: () {

                  setState(() {
                    isOpen = true;
                  });

                  shareUserProfile();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
```